# Making an angle just drawing a single line from focus in ellipse

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to make angle just by drawing a line ($r$ and $\theta$). I want to draw the following diagram.

[image]

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
\draw[](-2,0) -- (2,0);
\draw[](0,-1) -- (0,1);
% \draw[fill=black](0,0) circle (1 pt) node [above, right]{$O$};
\draw[fill=black](1,0) circle (1 pt);
\draw [<->] (-1.9,-0.1) -- (0.9,-0.1) node [midway,below]{$r_\text{max}$};
\draw [<->] (1.1,-0.1) -- (1.9,-0.1) node [midway,below]{$r_\text{min}$};
\draw [<->] (0,1.1) -- (2,1.1) node [midway,above]{$a$};
\draw [<->] (2.1,1.1) -- (2.1,0) node [midway,right]{$b$};
\draw [<-] (-0.1,0.1) -- (-1.5,1) node [end,left]{geometrical center};
\draw [<-] (1,-0.1) -- (1.4,-1) node [end,right]{centre of attraction};
\end{tikzpicture}
Elliptical Orbit
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

My output
[image]

Comment: The [`angles` library](https://tikz.dev/library-angle) will be helpful once you know where that line will point to on the ellipse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can define three coordintes at the points that define the angle: the point at the ellipse, the focus (centre of attraction) and the right end of the x-axis.

Then, as [Qrrbrbirlbel](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/16595/qrrbrbirlbel) suggests, you can use the `\pic` defined in the `angles` Ti*k*Z library to draw the angle specifying those points. And using the quotes library too is easy to add the label.

For example (I removed the `end` style for the nodes, not defined):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for \text
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,quotes}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw (0,0) ellipse (2cm and 1cm);
\draw[](-2,0) -- (2,0) coordinate (A); % <-- a coordinate here
\draw[](0,-1) -- (0,1);
% \draw[fill=black](0,0) circle (1 pt) node [above, right]{$O$};
\draw[fill=black] (1,0) coordinate (F) circle (1 pt); % another coordinate at the focus (angle vertex)
\draw [<->] (-1.9,-0.1) -- (0.9,-0.1)  node [midway,below]{$r_\text{max}$};
\draw [<->] (1.1,-0.1)  -- (1.9,-0.1)  node [midway,below]{$r_\text{min}$};
\draw [<->] (0,1.1)     -- (2,1.1)     node [midway,above]{$a$};
\draw [<->] (2.1,1.1)   -- (2.1,0)     node [midway,right]{$b$};
\draw [<-]  (-0.1,0.1)  -- (-1.5,1)    node [left]{geometrical center};
\draw [<-]  (1,-0.1)    -- (1.4,-1)    node [right]{centre of attraction};
% LINE AND ANGLE
\draw (F) -- (40:2cm and 1cm) node[midway,above] {$r$} coordinate (P); % <-- and the last coordinate
\pic[draw,"$\theta$",angle radius=0.4cm,angle eccentricity=1.4] {angle={A--F--P}};
%            label                         label position
\end{tikzpicture}

Elliptical Orbit
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]